# method .matches String false, how to have matches true

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check if a string ends with a point and 2 or 3 characters.
The regex I use is:

```
[.][a-z0-9A-Z][a-z0-9A-Z][a-z0-9A-Z]$
```

String example: `qsdgfdssdh.nfo`

It should return true but it always returns false.

Can you help me?

Thanks

Comment: @ErnestKiwele: The OP is perfectly clear about what is wanted: "if a string ends with a point and 2 or 3 characters". Under many interpretations, the pattern in fact does match the string. To someone who knows the answer, the answer is clear (Java's `matches` anchors against the whole string), but this does not change the fact that the OP's question is perfectly well-posed; there is no reason to shame them.

Answer (score 1):

The `String#matches` function applies the pattern to the *entire* string.  So the following should work:

```
String input = "qsdgfdssdh.nfo";
if (input.matches(".*\\.[0-9A-Za-z]{3}")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

If you're wondering what your current pattern would match with `String#matches`, it would match `.nfo`:

```
String input = ".nfo";
if (input.matches("\\.[0-9A-Za-z]{3}")) {
    System.out.println("match");
}
```

### Demo

Comment: Upvoted, but note that `\w` is different from OP's `[A-Za-z0-9]` (it includes underscore).